# Error Code: 10944642 Error Message: Error: Inbound SOAP Message - Session Token is missing

Tags: php, soap, wsdl, siebel

I am trying to call siebel wsdl,

```
    $wsdl = '/home/netvibes/mysw/public/r2/img/isusertrusted.wsdl';

    $client = new SoapClient($wsdl, array(
                        "trace"=>1,
                        "exceptions"=>0));
    $auth = array(
        'UsernameToken' => 'EXTAPP',
        'PasswordText' => 'EXTAPP'
    );

    $header = new SoapHeader('NAMESPACE', 'Auth', $auth, false);

    $client->__setSoapHeaders($header);

    $result = $client->__call('Execute_Service', array('appthai123zz@zzhotmail.swk')    );
```

I dont know what i am doing wrong, but when i do this i get,

```
    Error Code: 10944642 Error Message: Error: Inbound SOAP Message - Session Token is missing
```

May be something is wrong with the header. can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

This error is typical when you send a message that is missing the session token tag. This token is sent back by Siebel after the initial login, which prevents having to log in for each message - reducing the authentication overhead.